# Xamarin Date Slider Chart Control?

Tags: charts, slider

I'm looking to add a control that looks something like this:

[image]

The control must have selectable/clickable data points and each data point displays as a chart.  Any idea how to achieve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using [Syncfusion Charts control](https://www.syncfusion.com/xamarin-ui-controls/xamarin-charts).

Step 1: Find the custom control file from attached sample add it in your application.

Step 2: Initialize the SliderChart to view

Step 3: Add itemsource, XBindingPath and YBindingPath like below code snippet

```
<Control:SliderChart x:Name="sliderChart" MinimumValue="22" MaximumValue="30" Grid.Row="1"HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"  ItemsSource="{Binding Data,Source={x:Reference viewmodel}}" XBindingPath="XValue" YBindingPath="YValue"/>
```

[Sample here](http://%20https://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/general/ze/SfChartDemo204297880.zip)

[Video here](https://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/general/ze/SfChartDemo-1532917455.zip)

Screenshot
[image]